# calling parent window functions from popup window using Javascript

Tags: javascript, popup

I open a popup window and would like to call the function on the parent window from the popup window.
I would like this to work with IE, FF and Chrome. I am able to get it to work with IE, by using window.opener, but the same doesnt work on Chrome. Could you please help me on this?

Regards
Abishek

Comment: have you checked this https://developer.mozilla.org/en/working_with_windows_in_chrome_code ?

Comment: `window.opener` does work in Chrome. Could you post some code?

Comment: Tim is right. `window.opener` **does** work in Chrome. I came here because I wasn't sure if the original question was even possible. I actually didn't notice Tim's comment until I had done my own testing.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage

The compatibility is not 100%, you might be able to get more compatibility using sockets, but that's only if you're really comfortable with them and this isn't a really high performance site.

I would just try the post message interface.  Can't give much of a code example unless you give more info.